# Why is GWT CellTable rendering incorrectly in my installation of Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt, internet-explorer-9, celltable, gwt-celltable

I am developing a Java GWT & App Engine application and use a CellTable to display items uploaded by users into the Blobstore.

It all works fine, and looks like this:

[image: Firefox rendering]

But today I noticed a problem in my IE9. I know it's only my version of IE9 as it works fine on another computer using IE9 standard settings, and works fine in IE8 as well.

It looks like the JavaScript that renders the table isn't running correctly, but scripts are enabled as otherwise the app wouldn't run at all. This is what I'm seeing:

[image: Internet Explorer is rubbish]

I have tried resetting my IE9 to factory defaults in IE but I still get the problem.

I can't uninstall and reinstall because in true Microsoft style, it doesn't appear in the uninstall programs menu. *facepalm*

I can't install it again over itself because it is already installed :/

If anyone has any ideas, or can point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue when I had the Chrome Frame plugin installed.  I could only reproduce it in IE9 32bit.

**Fix**

- Uninstall the Chrome Frame plugin if you have that installed.
- If you still see this issue, or do not have Chrome Frame, try disabling/uninstalling other IE plugins to see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Uninstalled it and it works now! Thanks a ton. Not to others that disabling it isn't enough, and you can't uninstall the plugin from IE itself - it is installed as an actual program, not just an addon in IE. Ref: http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=161796

Answer (score 1):

Eureka! I have faced the same problem and spent about two days to solve it.

So, the solution:

Add the following tag to your main html file

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">`

When Chrome frame see that tag, it automatically switches on the Chrome (web-kit) engine on IE and all content will be shown correctly.